# Deserialize a JSON array

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize JSON data in C# using Newtonsoft namespace.

Here are my classes:

```
class lastResponse
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    // public string[] course { get; set; }
    public List<object> course { get; set; }
    public string publisher { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public string bookID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
}
```

This code:

```
var errorMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<lastResponse>(downloader.LastResponse);
```

Gives me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'BookManager.lastResponse' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Please help me figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: Can you show `downloader.LastResponse` this `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most possible reason for this could be the json you're getting from `downloader.LastResponse` is not an array.

Your Json could be like this.

```
{
    "type": "First",
    "metadata": {
        "bookID": "book123",
        "title": "bookTitle Here",
        "filename": "book file name"
    },
    "course": [
        {
            "1": "01",
            "2": "02"
        },
        {
            "001": "001",
            "002": "002"
        }
    ],
    "publisher": "you"
}
```

What you need to change is either pass JSON array in `downloader.LastResponse` or you can change your deserialize object statement as follows.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<lastResponse>(downloader.LastResponse);
```

According to what you're doing the correct JSON will be like this.

```
**[**
    {
        "type": "First",
        "metadata": {
            "bookID": "book123",
            "title": "bookTitle Here",
            "filename": "book file name"
        },
        "course": [
            {
                "1": "01",
                "2": "02"
            },
            {
                "001": "001",
                "002": "002"
            }
        ],
        "publisher": "you"
    }
**]**
```

This might solve your problem :)

Comment: I tried changing the deserialise statement  but it gives me this error ""An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'BookManager.lastResponse' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."" and the jason returned from the downloader.last response looks like the example you have on the first block

Comment: @SthokoManqele Can you share your json?

Comment: {  
      "type":"book",
      "metadata":{  
         "bookID":"book-000f6b3e-f616-4417-b1b8-66f375e3e4b4",
         "title":"Interactive Asset Test Book",
         "filename":"Interactive Demo",
      },
      "course":[  
         "301-Lieb Demo"
      ],
      "publisher":"ITS",
   }

Comment: @SthokoManqele Your JSON is not valid. First Validate it. Correct JSON is 
`{"type":"book","metadata":{"bookID":"book-000f6b3e-f616-4417-b1b8-66f375e3e4b4","title":"Interactive Asset Test Book","filename":"Interactive Demo"},"course":["301-Lieb Demo"],"publisher":"ITS" }` You can validate your json on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: downloader.lastResponse returns a valid JSON, this is an example. I just omitted a few things from my code because I am working with complex data

Comment: @SthokoManqele if you're using correct json then it'll definitely not throw an error. if you'll share your code then i can help. whatever you're providing i'm giving you solution accordingly.

Comment: thank you for you assistance, the problem was not with the json it was the way I was displaying the data

Answer (score 0):

you can use [javascriptserializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string s = "YouJsonText";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize(s);
//or
YouCustomClass res = serializer.Deserialize<YouCustomClass>(sb.ToString());
```

Also, you can use CustomJsonConverter like this:

```
public class YouCustomClassConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
  public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type,                      JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

   //and first you need register type, which you want Deserialize
   public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
   {
      get { return new[] { typeof(YouCustomClass ) }; }
   }

}

//and then example of using JavaScriptSerializer with custom converter
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ser.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new YouCustomClassConverter() });
try
{
     YouCustomClass obj = ser.Deserialize(jsonString);
}
```

Note: you need use `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`